# Returning from a parent function from inside a child function - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm relatively new to coding in JavaScript, and I've came across a problem. I like to nest functions to keep things orderly, but how would I exit from a parent function from inside a child function?

example:

```
function foo1() {
   function foo2() {
      //return foo1() and foo2()?
   }
   foo2();
}
```

Comment: Without more example code it would be hard to envision a reason why anyone would want to try this. This example code does not even compile.

Comment: I'm making a game... I have all my games code in "play()" and inside play i want the function "die()" to stop "play()"

Comment: *"I'm making a game... I have all my games code in "play()" and inside play i want the function "die()" to stop "play()""* If your game involves interacting with the outside world in anyway, it seems really unlikely that `play` will still be running when you decide that something should "die", because of the asynchronous way most JavaScript environments (including browsers) handle user-initiated events.

Comment: What environment is this game run in?

Answer (score 13):

*See update under the fold*

You can't. You can only return from the child function, and then return from the parent function.

<s>I should note that in your example, nothing ever calls `foo2`</s> *(As of your edit, something does)*. Let's look at a more real example (and one that comes up a lot): Let's say we want know if an array contains an entry matching some criterion. A first stab might be:

```
function doesArrayContainEntry(someArray) {
    someArray.forEach(function(entry) {
        if (entryMatchesCondition(entry)) {
            return true; // Yes it does           <-- This is wrong
        }
    });
    return false; // No it doesn't
}
```

You can't directly do that. Instead, you have to return from your anonymous iterator function in a way to stop the `forEach` loop. Since `forEach` doesn't offer a way to do that, you use `some`, which does:

```
function doesArrayContainEntry(someArray) {
    return someArray.some(function(entry) {
        if (entryMatchesCondition(entry)) {
            return true; // Yes it does
        }
    });
}
```

`some` returns `true` (and stops looping) if any call to the iterator function returns `true`; it returns `false` if no call to the iterator returned `true`.

Again, that's just one common example.

---

You've referred to `setInterval` below, which tells me that you're almost certainly doing this in a browser environment.

If so, your `play` function almost certainly has already returned by the time you want to do what you're talking about, assuming the game has any interaction with the user other than `alert` and `confirm`. This is because of the asynchronous nature of the environment.

For example:

```
function play() {
    var health = 100;

    function handleEvent() {
        // Handle the event, impacting health
        if (health < 0 {
            // Here's where you probably wanted to call die()
        }
    }

    hookUpSomeEvent(handleEvent);
}
```

The thing is, that `play` will run and return almost immediately. Then the browser waits for the event you hooked up to occur, and if it does, it triggers the code in `handleEvent`. But `play` has long-since returned.

Comment: Do you have any recommendations of something I could do?

Comment: Well, it depends on what we understand by "return". Raising an exception will propagate.

Comment: Return a bool (true/false), depending on if the function is successful or not, then have the parent function determine what to do next.

Comment: Wouldn't I have to have a setInterval or something to continually check?

Comment: @user3025700: If you're doing anything like that, your `play` will have already returned.

Answer (score 2):

Make a note whether the parent function should also return.

```
function foo1() {
    bool shouldReturn = false;

    function foo2() {
        shouldReturn = true;    // put some logic here to tell if foo1() should also return 
        return;
    }

    if (shouldReturn) {
        return;
    } else {
        // continue
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

##### It only says that you can't `return` the parent function in the child function, but we can do a callback and make it happen.

```js
function foo1(cb = () => null) {
   function foo2() {
      cb();
   }

   foo2();
}

foo1(() => {
    // do something
});
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use [`Promises`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) for this:

```js
const fun1 = async () => {
    const shouldReturn = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // in-game logic...
        resolve(true)
    })

    if(shouldReturn) return;
}
```

if you wanna return from the parent function, then just resolve with `true`

Answer (score -1):

Based on your comment, something like this might work as a main game loop.

```
function play() {

var stillPlaying = true;
    while(stillPlaying) {
     ... play game ...
      stillPlaying = false; // set this when some condition has determined you are done
    }
}
```

Comment: Couldn't that generate a loop that crashes the browser?